# Php Присвоить значение ключу массива через замыкание

Tags: php, массивы, замыкания

Имеется массив.

```
  $report = array();
                $report ['tasks'] = [
                    'report_field' => '1',

                    'report' => function () {
                        $i = 'ok';
                        return $i;
                    }
                ];
```

Необходимо, используя замыкание, присвоить значение ключу. В данном случае **report** 
Если делать **var_dump** массива, то получаю **object(Closure)#1 (0) { }** 
Если делать **echo $report['tasks']['report']**, то получаю Ошибку 500.
Зачем тогда замыкания в PHP или я чего-то не понимаю?
По мне так полезность замыканий была бы в возможности обработке данных перед присваиванием их к ключу массива.

Comment: вы наверное до конца не понимаете что такое замыкание )

Comment: print_r($report['tasks']['report']());

Comment: получается, что через замыкание я не могу присвоить значение ключу массива?
Мне необходимо, чтобы здесь  $report['tasks']['report'] появилось значение- результат работы функции

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$report = [
    'tasks' => [
        'report_field' => 1,
        'report' => function() {
            echo 'test string';
        }
    ]
];

$call = $report['tasks']['report'];
$call();
```

Comment: `$call();` или `echo $call();`

Comment: Всё равно не так как я хотел.
Почему-то у меня сложилось впечатление, что замыкание можно использовать в массивах.
В общем решил свой вопрос тем, что обрабатываю данные до массива, а не в массиве.
К тому же я конвертирую массив в json и отдаю по сети.

Comment: `json_encode` не поддерживает замыкания, которые делаются в массиве